# Only receiving "File Written To" notifications from VDKQueue regardless of activity

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, vdkqueue

I am trying to implement VDKQueue but only get ‘VDKQueueFileWrittenToNotification’ back as the notification regardless of the file activity in the watched folder. Deletes, file size changes all report back as this same message.

I think everything is set up OK, but maybe not…

```
[self.theQueueWatcher setDelegate:self];
self.theQueueWatcher.alwaysPostNotifications=YES;
[self.theQueueWatcher addPath:self.hotFolderPath notifyingAbout:VDKQueueNotifyDefault];
```

This is on 10.8.2.

Does anyone know if anything underlying in the OS has changed which would cause this? Or what I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

After contacting the author of VDKQueue, he helpfully(seems like a nice guy) pointed out the purpose of kQueue, and therefore VDKQueue, was to watch an individual file for changes etc, not a folder as I was doing. So now starts the voyage into FSEvents which Bryan recommended was the best way to achieve this task.

Thanks Bryan.

Hope someone else finds this useful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing discussion. I was also wondering why am I always getting same notification.

Comment: Do you have any FSEvents wrapper?